# jQuery / Href parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm look for a way I can have a list of countries using ... so when you click on a link, the country code parameter is passed over to qjuery which will inturn return a list of cities.

I have been able to do all this using a  dropdown, but want to change it to a.href links.

Something like the below...

```
$('#country').click(function(event) {  
// get the countryCode value here
var $country=$("a#country").val();
...
```

These need to pass countryCode

```
<a href="#" id="country">Australia</a>
<a href="#" id="country">United Kingdom</a>
<a href="#" id="country">NewZealand</a>
```

Comment: I suggest that id should be unique. and .val() returns null. Use .html() instead.

Comment: Using the same "id" for multiple elements is incorrect.  You can use a "class" instead.

Comment: anchor tags don't have a value. What you want is it's text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In html5 its best to use [custom attribute](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/):

```
<a href="#" class="country" data-code="au">Australia</a>
<a href="#" class="country" data-code="uk">United Kingdom</a>
<a href="#" class="country" data-code="nz">NewZealand</a>
```

In JS:

```
$('.country').click(function(event) {  
    var $country = $(this).data('code');
}
```

Comment: You can't have them all with the ID country.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm sure a few of these would have worked, but I've gone straight to the one at the top and it's done exactly what I was hoping.  Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change that `id` to a `class` and do:

```
$(".country").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var country = $(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you shouldn't have multiple items with the same `id`.

You could store the country code as data:

```
<a href="#" class="country" data-country="aus">Australia</a>
```

And then retrieve it:

```
$('.country').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var country = $(this).data('country');
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="#" class="c" id="country1">Australia</a>
<a href="#" class="c" id="country2">United Kingdom</a>
<a href="#"  class="c" id="country3">NewZealand</a>


$('.c').click(function(event) {  

event.prenventDefault(); 
var $country=$(this).html();
//var $country=$(this).text(); //or you can try this.
//...
});
```

Comment: No.  `$("a#country")` won't work as you expect since IDs are supposed to be unique.